# Transforming Vertices by Joints with Smooth Skinning

Tags: c++, animation, matrix, directx, skinning

I'm having an issue when trying to animate a mesh within my game using smooth skinning. I'm exporting a mesh, it's joints, and all animation data from Maya and it's importing properly within the game. I've also got my joints displayed in-game as spheres, just to make sure they are animating properly, and they are. I'm having trouble when transforming the vertices to bone space, and I'm clueless as to why. Here's a basic run-down of what I'm currently doing.

- Precalculating the inverse of each bone in it's bind-pose. The bone
  hierarchy is also set up here, I'm only setting their local matrices
  as their world matrices are calculated upon request.
- Interpolating matrices between keyframes, this appears to be working
  as the spheres are animating correctly.
- Copying the meshes vertices from the bind-pose into a seperate buffer
  to be modified
- Transforming each vertex:

  For each vertex

  ```
   For each influencing bone in vertex

             Vertex tempvert;
             tempvert  = vertex.position * local bone inverse matrix;
             tempvert  = tempvert * world interpolated bone transform;
             tempvert *= influence weight;
             vertex   += tempvert;
  ```
- Update the GPU with the transformed vertices

I've also tried switching around local and world transforms for the bones, but to no avail. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid, I just want to make sure that's the case before I go tearing apart my math library.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say "the inverse of each bone in it's bind-pose", is this the matrix that transforms from skin coordinates to bone coordinates?

Comment: Yes, so then it can be transformed by the appropriate bone.

Comment: And then the "local interpolated bone transform" transforms from the animated bone coordinates back to skin coordinates?

Comment: Yes, that is the interpolation of the bones world matrix between the current and next frame. I was incorrect by saying it was local.

Comment: Then I don't see anything you are doing wrong from what you have posted.  Can you give a simple example of where it isn't working?  For example, the particular multiplications that one vertex goes through and how the result is different from what you want.

Comment: Also, are you weights normalized?

Comment: After transforming from skin to bone coordinates, everything seems okay. The transform is a negative identity matrix with -1.33f in the WAxis's Y coordinate, so the vertex in bone coordinates results in (-1.0, 1.33, -1.0). Seems okay... Apparently some of my bone transforms have some scattered garbage values that I've not found until now, which would explain the behavior I'm getting. That's embarrassing! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!